# NullPointerException during getSize

Tags: java

I am in trouble. I am wondering how to fix it about 2 hours and i still know nothing. Can you help me guys? 
I've written this code once again but it doesn't change anything, still do not know where did i mistake.

```
public class Historia {
public ArrayList<String> tablica;

public void odczyt() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("skarbonka.bin"));
    tablica = (ArrayList<String>) objectInputStream.readObject();
    objectInputStream.close();
    int size = tablica.size();
    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
        System.out.println(tablica.get(i));
    }

}
```

There's second class:

```
public class Zapis {
private GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
private Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
private Historia dodaj = new Historia();

public void plik() throws IOException {
    Dane dane = new Dane();
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("skarbonka.bin"));
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    dane.kwota = scanner.nextInt();
    dane.dzien = String.format("%tc", gregorianCalendar);
    int g = dodaj.tablica.size();
    for(int i=0; i<g; i++){
        arrayList.add("");
        arrayList.set(i, dodaj.tablica.get(i));
    }

    arrayList.add(dane.toString());
    objectOutputStream.writeObject(arrayList);
    objectOutputStream.close();
}
```

}

[image: There's the error]

Any ideas? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
public ArrayList<String> tablica;
```

is never initialized, thus null when you call

```
int g = dodaj.tablica.size();
```

Change the declaration to

```
private List<String> tablica = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Also note that it's usually advisable to code against Interfaces, so prefer List as type instead of ArrayList.

Furthermore, make your members private with getters/setters.

Generally, your code doesn't make much sense to me, would be interesting what you intend to do?

Comment: It had to be something as a piggy bank which shows my account status and the day on which has changed. 
Thanks for your help, but now i noticed next gap. My input shows just last entry. Why?  I thought   for(int i=0; i<g; i++){
        arrayList.add("");
        arrayList.set(i, dodaj.tablica.get(i)); will save entire table

Answer (score 1):

You should initialized ArrayList !

```
ArrayList<Object> list =new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Comment: Thanks mate! but now i noticed next gap. My input shows just last entry. Why? I thought for(int i=0; i<g; i++){ arrayList.add(""); arrayList.set(i, dodaj.tablica.get(i)); will save entire table .